# Why is life cycle not running

Tags: asp.net, lifecycle

I have 2 pages in an asp.net website:

- Page 1 contains objects.
- Page 2 contains information about one of the objects.

There is something that I do not understand, and I hope some of you can explain it.

I click an object on page 1 and it is shown on page 2, but when I hit the back button in the browser, onpreinit, oninit and evertything else is not called on page 1. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hitting 'back' doesn't resubmit GET requests to the server, its just returning your cached copy.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the "back" button on the browser the request is typically not resubmitted. It is in fact a cached version of the previous page.

You can add tags to the HTML to tell browsers to not cache the page:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

These tags should be used together according to the HTML Spec:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.32

> When the no-cache directive is present in a request message, an
>   application SHOULD forward the request toward the origin server even
>   if it has a cached copy of what is being requested. This pragma
>   directive has the same semantics as the no-cache cache-directive (see
>   section 14.9) and is defined here for backward compatibility with
>   HTTP/1.0. Clients SHOULD include both header fields when a no-cache
>   request is sent to a server not known to be HTTP/1.1 compliant.

ASP.net has it's own caching controls seen below:

MSDN Page Caching: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9s3a17d.aspx

MSDN ASP.net Caching: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c.aspx